# Distance Formula Problem

Tags: analytic-geometry

If two vertices of an equilateral triangle are $(1, -1)$ and $(-\sqrt{3}, - \sqrt{3})$, find the coordinates of the third vertex.

Step by Step procedure to get the answer.

Take $A=(1, -1)$, $B=(-\sqrt{3}, - \sqrt{3})$.
Let the third vertex be $C=(x, y)$.

The distance d between the two points $A=(x_1, y_1)$ and $B=(x_2, y_2)$ is given by the formula 
$$
d= \sqrt{ (x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2 }
$$
So we get the distance $AB = 2 \sqrt{2}$
. Similarly we have to find the distance between BC & AC using distance formula where we get the equation in the form of x & y even though the distance is $2\sqrt{2}$ because it is equilateral triangle. But the correct solution is not able to get. Please help.

Comment: What have you tried? I would start by drawing a picture with all the relevant information. Also, why is the title "Distance formula problem", when in the question you're only talking about a triangle? and nothing mentioned about any distances?

Comment: Plz try. But answer is difficult to get in correct form.

Comment: So what did you figure out so far? It sounds like you did get some result ...

Comment: I tried all methods. This problem is from Analytical Geometry. I could not get the correct simplified answer. Plz help.

Comment: If you want the methods I used to find, I can share it with you, the step by step procedures.

Comment: Yes, please write what you figured out so far, in the body of the post.

Comment: Or please provide your email id where I can send you my worked method by scanning the note book.

Comment: Sir, finding difficult to answer. Take your own time.

Comment: Here's a similar problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1183349/find-the-coordinate-of-third-point-of-equilateral-triangle

Comment: Sir, I have gone through the problem & understood. In same way I have tried but the answer is not coming. You can please check by trying.

Comment: It looks like you know how to solve it, what is the problem? Here is a video of a very similar problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAiy38k3Sh4

Comment: Sir, gone through the video also. But while solving this problem you get difficult to get the correct answer. Please try.

Comment: Check the problem, make sure you got the coordinates right. The solution does seem ugly. Initially you said that the first vertex is $(1,-1)$ then you wrote $(-1,1)$

Comment: @ClubPlayer, when you follow the logic in the example solution, and plug in your own results, what is the quadratic equation you get (equivalent to the last equation in the StackExchange solution)?

Comment: Sorry Sir. I corrected it to A=(1,-1).

Comment: Still the equation becomes bit difficult even after plugging the coordinates. Hence please try yourself.

Comment: Sir, tried now also. Not able to get the correct solution. Please help.

Comment: Do you have an answer?

Comment: Americo Tavares Sir, A BIG THANK YOU because I have been trying to contact you over facebook, email etc. to get your simple yet effective answer. But all failed even with proper technical knowledge. Your knowledge is vast and like mathematical. With respectfulness I learned it from you. Now I have saved your answer in my system as I was not aware of the fact that the answer gets deleted here. Sorry if I have troubled you Sir. My email id is haideep76@gmail.com

Answer (score 2):

Distance between two given points will be the side of the triangle $a=\sqrt{(1+\sqrt{3})^2+(\sqrt{3}-1)^2}=2\sqrt{2}$. Now you just need to draw two circles of radius $a$ and with centers at the known vertices. The equations of the circles are:

$(x-1)^2+(y+1)^2=8$
$(x+\sqrt{3})^2+(y+\sqrt{3})^2=8$
The circles will intersect at two points and to find the coordinates you need to solve this system:$$ \begin{cases}
(x-1)^2+(y+1)^2=(x+\sqrt{3})^2+(y+\sqrt{3})^2 \\[2ex]
(x-1)^2+(y+1)^2=8
\end{cases}$$
$$ \begin{cases}
x^2-2x+1+y^2+2y+1=x^2+2\sqrt{3}x+3+y^2+2\sqrt{3}y+3 \\[2ex]
(x-1)^2+(y+1)^2=8
\end{cases}$$
$$ \begin{cases}
x^2-2x+1+y^2+2y+1=x^2+2\sqrt{3}x+3+y^2+2\sqrt{3}y+3 \\[2ex]
(x-1)^2+(y+1)^2=8
\end{cases}$$

$$ \begin{cases}
y(2-2\sqrt{3})=x(2+2\sqrt{3})+4 \\[2ex]
(x-1)^2+(y+1)^2=8
\end{cases}$$

$$ \begin{cases}
y=\frac{x(1+\sqrt{3})+2}{1-\sqrt{3}} \\[2ex]
(x-1)^2+(y+1)^2=8
\end{cases}$$Finally, we get a quadratic equation for $x$: $$x^2-2x+1+\Big(\frac{x(1+\sqrt{3})+2}{1-\sqrt{3}}+1\Big)^2=8 $$ The solutions are: $x=-1, x=2-\sqrt{3}$. We already have $y$ expressed via $x$ so just plug the $x$ values in that equation and find $y$.

Comment: Sir, trying to understand your method.

Comment: The answer is C=(-1, 1)

Comment: @ClubPlayer: That's one of the answers. Yes, when $x=-1, y=1$. When $x=2-\sqrt{3}, y=-2-\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: There was an easy answer by retired electrical engineer with showing the Graph with two triangles. I have not deleted that answer. But I am not able to get that answer. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using complex numbers. The two vertices are $A(a=1-i)$ and $B(b=-\sqrt{3}-i\sqrt{3})$ and  $C(c)$ the third vertex . $a$ and $b$ are affix with respect to $A$ and $B$. Now we consider the complex $s=\frac{b-a}{b-c}$. If ABC is equilateral then $|s|=1$ and $\arg(s)=\pm\frac{\pi}{3}$ which mean: $s=e^{\pm\frac{\pi}{3}}$.
Since $c=b-\frac{b-a}{s}=b-(b-a)\bar{s}$ we can easily compute $c$.

Comment: Sir, beyond my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Equilateral triangle

$A=(1,-1)$

$B=(-\sqrt{3},-\sqrt{3})$

$C=(x,y)$

$|AB|=2\sqrt{2}$

height of an equilateral triangle:

$h=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}a$

$a=|AB|$

$h=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}.2\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{6}$

noting that

$|BO|=\sqrt{(0-(-\sqrt{3}))^2+(0-(-\sqrt{3}))^2}=\sqrt{6}$

O = (0,0) origin Cartesian Cordinate System

BO is foot of the altitude

O is midpoint de CA

$\frac{xC+1}{2}=0⇒xC=-1$

$\frac{yC+(-1)}{2}=0⇒yC=1$
[image: equilateral triangle]
C=(-1,1)

Answer (score -1):

After writing the equations of the two circles to find the points of intersection, I found the resulting quadratic equations to be too tedious for my patience.  Instead, I determined the (parametric) vector from $(-\sqrt{3}, - \sqrt{3} )$ to $(1, -1)$ to be

$$A = \left(-\sqrt{3} + \left(1+\sqrt{3}\right) T, -\sqrt{3} + \left(-1+\sqrt{3}\right) T\right)$$ where $0 \le T \le 1$.

I then added $(\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{3})$ to this to translate it to the origin, then multiplied it 
by the rotation matrix $\begin{bmatrix} \cos &  -\sin \\ \sin & \cos \end{bmatrix}$, using $\theta = +60^{\circ}$ and $T=1$.  Lastly, 
I subtracted $(\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{3})$ to translate back.  After MANY sign corrections, I got 
one of the two possible points to be $(-1,1)$, which checks out using the distance formula.
No quadratics to solve, just vectors to add and rotate.

(Sorry about my lack of proper math notation formatting; if I find this site to be interesting, I will learn MathJax.)

Comment: Sir, Answer is correct. But what is the method?

Comment: CP, Are you familiar with 2 dimensional vectors and the 2x2 rotation matrix, and multiplying a vector by a matrix (linear algebra, I think) ?

Comment: That last equation in Vasya's answer scares me.  I thought it would end up as a very nasty quadratic.  I'm curious if it simplifies enough to solve by hand (in a reasonable amount of time), or if Mathematica or some such was used to solve for x.

Comment: Sir, I am familiar with only distance formula and quadratic equations. Not with others. So please explain with same method if possible.

Comment: Without vectors, I think Vasya's solution is what you're looking for.  A slightly different method would be to write the equation for the circle centered on (1, -1) (as Vasya did), then write the equation for the perpendicular bisector of the two given points (slightly easier equation to solve than the 2nd circle).  Two equations (one linear), two unknowns .  I tried to solve it by hand, but must have made mistake(s) and got the wrong answer.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For typesetting, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).